# multi attribute array syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble finding the correct syntax for the following array I am trying to create. If anyone could point out where I am going wrong it would be much appreciated. I want to generate a random movie on the click of a button; however stuck on this syntax.

Thanks

```js
var thrillers =  [],
movieInfo[0] =   ("The Soccer Nanny", 5.7, 2011, "Drama", 94),
movieInfo[1] =   ( "Dawg Fight", 7.3, 2015 , "Sport", 79,
movieInfo[2] =   ( "Anatomy of a Love Seen", 5.2, 2014, "Romantic", 80),
movieInfo[3] =   ( "JFK – Director’s Cut", 8, 1991, "Thriller", 205),
movieInfo[4] =   ( "Common", 7.4, 2014, "Drama", 93),
movieInfo[5] =   ( "Altar", 6.1, 2014, "Horror", 88),
movieInfo[6] =   ( "Pokémon the Movie: Genesect and the Legend Awakened", 5.3, 2013, "Children", 71),
movieInfo[7] =   ( "Boy Meets Girl", 6.7, 2014, "Romantic", 99),
movieInfo[8] =   ( "Jack Irish: Dead Point", 6.6, 2014, "Thriller", 83),
movieInfo[9] =   ( "Jack Irish: Black Tide", 6.6, 2012, "Thriller", 93),
movieInfo[10] =  ( "Jack Irish: Bad Debts", 6.6, 2012, "Thriller", 99),
movieInfo[11] =  ( "He Who Dares", 2.9, 2014, "Action", 82),
movieInfo[12] =  ( "The King Is Dead!", 5.5, 2012, "Comedy", 106),
movieInfo[13] =  ( "Julia X", 4.5, 2011, "Horror", 92);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of arrays, you use the same syntax for the inner ones as the outer ones:

```
var thrillers = [];
thrillers[0] = ["The Soccer Nanny", 5.7, 2011, "Drama", 94];
thrillers[1] = ["Dawg Fight", 7.3, 2015 , "Sport", 79];
// ...
```

but you can do it all in one:

```
var thrillers = [
    ["The Soccer Nanny", 5.7, 2011, "Drama", 94],
    ["Dawg Fight", 7.3, 2015 , "Sport", 79],
    // ...
];
```

But I wouldn't do an array of arrays; I'd do an array of *objects*, with useful names for the parts of each object:

```
var thrillers = [
    {title: "The Soccer Nanny", something: 5.7, year: 2011, category: "Drama", rating: 94},
    {"Dawg Fight", something: 7.3, year: 2015 , category: "Sport", rating: 79},
    // ...
];
```

Then you use those like this:

```
console.log(thrillers[0].title); // "The Soccer Nanny"
```

and/or

```
var thriller = thrillers[0];
console.log(thriller.title); // "The Soccer Nanny"
```

Comment: Thanks very much, very helpful answer!